# python for loop over different lists not to be equal shows incorrect output

Tags: python

This is my python code:

```py
statuses = [
    {'id': '1', 'plan_id': '124124124', 'ip': '1.1.1.1', 'name': 'Saeed1', 'status': 'active'},
    {'id': '2', 'plan_id': '124224124', 'ip': '2.2.2.2', 'name': 'Saeed2', 'status': 'suspended'},
    {'id': '3', 'plan_id': '164124124', 'ip': '3.3.3.3', 'name': 'Saeed3', 'status': 'suspended'},
    {'id': '4', 'plan_id': '164124124', 'ip': '4.4.4.4', 'name': 'Saeed4', 'status': 'suspended'},
    {'id': '5', 'plan_id': '124124124', 'ip': '5.5.5.5', 'name': 'Saeed51', 'status': 'active'},
]
all_servers = [
    {'id': '1', 'name': 'Saeed1', 'addresses': {'External_Network': [{'addr': '1.1.1.1'}]}, 'plan': 'planA', 'status': 'suspended'},
    {'id': '2', 'name': 'Saeed2', 'addresses': {'External_Network': [{'addr': '6.6.6.6'}]}, 'plan': 'planB', 'status': 'suspended'},
    {'id': '3', 'name': 'Saeed3', 'addresses': {'External_Network': [{'addr': '3.3.3.3'}]}, 'plan': 'planG', 'status': 'active'},
    {'id': '4', 'name': 'Saeed4', 'addresses': {}, 'plan': 'planC', 'status': 'active'},
    {'id': '5', 'name': 'Saeed5', 'addresses': {'External_Network': [{'addr': '8.8.8.8'}]}, 'plan': 'planA', 'status': 'suspended'},
]
all_plans = [
    {'name': 'planA', 'id': '124124124'},
    {'name': 'planB', 'id': '124224124'},
    {'name': 'planC', 'id': '164124124'},
    {'name': 'planG', 'id': '174124124'},
]

tmp = []
final = []
for status in statuses:
    for server in all_servers:
        for plan in all_plans:
            if status['id'] == server['id'] and status['id'] not in tmp:
                tmp.append(status['id'])
                if (status['plan_id'] != plan['id']) and (plan['name'] != server['plan']):
                    final.append({'name': status['name'], 'code': 'plan_mismatch'})
                if 'External_Network' not in server['addresses']:
                    final.append({'name': server['name'], 'code': 'has no ip'})
                else:
                    for addr in server['addresses']['External_Network']:
                        if addr['addr'] != status['ip']:
                            final.append({'name': status['name'], 'code': 'ip_mismatch'})
                if status['status'] != server['status']:
                    final.append({'name': status['name'], 'code': 'status_mismatch'})
                if status['name'] != server['name']:
                    final.append({'name': status['name'], 'code': 'names_mismatch'})
```

This is the logic I'm having:

```
from `statuses` and `all_servers`, first check if `id` matches, then do this:
1) if `status['plan_id'] != plan['id']` and also `plan['name'] != all['plan']`, print plan_mismatch
2)+ if `status['name'] != all['name']`, print names_mismatch.
3)+ if status['ip'] != all['addresses']['External_Network']['addr'], print ip_mismatch.
4)+ if status['status'] != all['status'], print status_mismatch.
```

Based on the current `final` list, these are the issues that shouldn't be here, but I don't know why:

1. {'name': 'Saeed2', 'code': 'plan_mismatch'}
2. {'name': 'Saeed4', 'code': 'plan_mismatch'}

All of the bugs to be printed should be these:

1. Saeed1 status_mismatch
2. Saeed2 ip_mismatch
3. Saeed3 plan_mismatch
4. Saeed3 status_mismatch
5. Saeed4 has no ip
6. Saeed4 status_mismatch
7. Saeed51 name_mismatch
8. Saeed51 ip_mismatch
9. Saeed51 status_mismatch

Comment: side note: don't use `all` as a variable (or iterator) name

Comment: @OrenIshShalom yes you're right. I forgot that's a keyword. I edit the question.

Comment: On the first iteration of the `for plan in all_plans:` loop, plan is `{'name': 'planA', 'id': '124124124'}`, and for Saeed2, `124224124` does not match `124124124` and `planA` does not match `planB`.

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks, but why other iterations don't say `plan_mismatch`? I mean the first iteration of others don't match the plan too

Comment: Because on the very first iteration, `status['id']` has not yet been added to `tmp`.

Comment: @JohnGordon ok, first checks the id, but regarding the plans, most of them  in the first iteration don't match. First iteration of plan is `planA` at first. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't understand why you are asking these questions.  It is a very simple matter to add some print statements to your code so that you can see exactly why it makes the decisions.  This kind of basic debugging is a core programming skill.

Comment: I think your code is adding a plan_mismatch error too soon.  It should add the error after it has checked all the plans and found that NONE of them match, instead of adding a plan_mismatch error right away when it finds ONE plan that does not match.

Comment: @JohnGordon I added that at first but I didn't understand the reason of having incorrect output., sorry man. I tried many things, including adding print to each step but I couldn't understand the issues.

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks, I was able to edit the code and reach the expected output, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, each `status` and `server` with the same `id` are compared with only the first `plan`.

The right *related* `plan` should be found and then compared with:

```py
statuses = [
    {'id': '1', 'plan_id': '124124124', 'ip': '1.1.1.1', 'name': 'Saeed1', 'status': 'active'},
    {'id': '2', 'plan_id': '124224124', 'ip': '2.2.2.2', 'name': 'Saeed2', 'status': 'suspended'},
    {'id': '3', 'plan_id': '164124124', 'ip': '3.3.3.3', 'name': 'Saeed3', 'status': 'suspended'},
    {'id': '4', 'plan_id': '164124124', 'ip': '4.4.4.4', 'name': 'Saeed4', 'status': 'suspended'},
    {'id': '5', 'plan_id': '124124124', 'ip': '5.5.5.5', 'name': 'Saeed51', 'status': 'active'},
]
all_servers = [
    {'id': '1', 'name': 'Saeed1', 'addresses': {'External_Network': [{'addr': '1.1.1.1'}]}, 'plan': 'planA', 'status': 'suspended'},
    {'id': '2', 'name': 'Saeed2', 'addresses': {'External_Network': [{'addr': '6.6.6.6'}]}, 'plan': 'planB', 'status': 'suspended'},
    {'id': '3', 'name': 'Saeed3', 'addresses': {'External_Network': [{'addr': '3.3.3.3'}]}, 'plan': 'planG', 'status': 'active'},
    {'id': '4', 'name': 'Saeed4', 'addresses': {}, 'plan': 'planC', 'status': 'active'},
    {'id': '5', 'name': 'Saeed5', 'addresses': {'External_Network': [{'addr': '8.8.8.8'}]}, 'plan': 'planA', 'status': 'suspended'},
]
all_plans = [
    {'name': 'planA', 'id': '124124124'},
    {'name': 'planB', 'id': '124224124'},
    {'name': 'planC', 'id': '164124124'},
    {'name': 'planG', 'id': '174124124'},
]

tmp = []
final = []
for status in statuses:
    for server in all_servers:
        if status['id'] == server['id'] and status['id'] not in tmp:
            tmp.append(status['id'])
            for plan in all_plans:
                if plan['id'] == status['plan_id']:
                    if plan['name'] != server['plan']:
                        final.append({'name': status['name'], 'code': 'plan_mismatch'})
                    break
            if 'External_Network' not in server['addresses']:
                final.append({'name': server['name'], 'code': 'has no ip'})
            else:
                for addr in server['addresses']['External_Network']:
                    if addr['addr'] != status['ip']:
                        final.append({'name': status['name'], 'code': 'ip_mismatch'})
            if status['status'] != server['status']:
                final.append({'name': status['name'], 'code': 'status_mismatch'})
            if status['name'] != server['name']:
                final.append({'name': status['name'], 'code': 'names_mismatch'})

print('\n'.join([str(f) for f in final]))
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'Saeed1', 'code': 'status_mismatch'}
{'name': 'Saeed2', 'code': 'ip_mismatch'}
{'name': 'Saeed3', 'code': 'plan_mismatch'}
{'name': 'Saeed3', 'code': 'status_mismatch'}
{'name': 'Saeed4', 'code': 'has no ip'}
{'name': 'Saeed4', 'code': 'status_mismatch'}
{'name': 'Saeed51', 'code': 'ip_mismatch'}
{'name': 'Saeed51', 'code': 'status_mismatch'}
{'name': 'Saeed51', 'code': 'names_mismatch'}
```